# Expo JS debugger pulling up a chrome tab that is not connected to the JS file

Tags: react-native, expo, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to React Native and need some help debugging my code. I cannot seem to access a debugger that works.

When opening the debugger from the terminal (j), a separate chrome DevTools tab opens that is seemingly not connected. In App.js, I've used a variable that hasn't been initialized. This error will be visible in the console, but it won't appear in the `Sources` tab of the DevTools.

I want Chrome DevTools to halt and highlight the line causing the error, but the 'App.js' file doesn't appear in the sources tab. I do have it configured to pause on caught exceptions.

What shows in the console:

````
This error is located at:
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes```
````

Comment: This error stops your app so you can not use devtools because it will disconnect.